# AngularJS controller with factroy reference not being called

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, controller, factory

I cannot seem to get a simple controller working when I add a factory reference (homeFactory) to the controller's function constructor. If I remove the factory reference, the controller works. Also, with the reference in the controller, the controller never even gets called when I breakpoint it, so it doesn't appear to be something wrong with the factory. The value on the view shows up as {{ account }}, curly braces and all. Basically, the factory is calling a webapi controller to get the current user's active directory name.

Controller (doesn't work):

```
app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, homeFactory) {
    $scope.message = 'This is a test Angular JS App';

    // get the account info from a webapi controller
    $scope.getAccount = function () {
        homeFactory.getAccount()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.status = '';
            $scope.account = data;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to get user account: ' + error;
        });
    };
});
```

Controller (works):

```
app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is a test Angular JS App';
    // pass a test value 
    $scope.account = 'Bob Jones'
});
```

Factory:

```
app.factory('homeFactory', function ($http) {
    var baseAddress = "../api/";
    var factory = {};
    // baseAddress and url are based on the 

    // call the webapi controller
    factory.getAccount = function () {
        url = baseAddress + "home/account";
        return $http.get(url);
    };

    return factory;
});
```

Routing mod:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'Partials/ViewStart.html'
    })
    .when('/view-start', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'Partials/ViewStart.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

ViewStart view:

```
<div class="container">
    <h4>This is the start view</h4>
    <div style="color: #000; font-size: .85em;">{{ account }}</div>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="account" />
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you just include the factory, but don't call any methods on it?

Comment: any console errors ?

Comment: You forgot a var here url = baseAddress + "home/account"; should be var url = baseAddress + "home/account";

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake on my part. I didn't include the script reference to my factory's javascript file in the main page. I was going to delete this post but figured I leave it in case someone else is having a similar issue.